# Who organised the Belleau Wood cemetery visit on November 10th 2018?

Tags: united-states, france

Was yesterday’s United States visit to the Aisne-Marne American cemetery in Belleau Wood, fifty miles east of Paris, organised by President Macron?

In other words: was it a bilateral event, or merely a United States event on French soil?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not too sure but based off [this article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/europe/trump-and-macron-meet-whats-left-to-talk-about/2018/11/10/680a014c-e1ec-11e8-ba30-a7ded04d8fac_story.html) it appears that President Macron is the host and therefore it is likely to be a bilateral event:

> there were some visible signs of strain between **Trump and his host**
>   amid tensions over Macron’s call for a “true European army”

Comment: I have added an excerpt that suggests that Macron is the host as the link might break in the future (there is also some form of paywall).